# How to read and split the data without using numpy or pandas in Python?

Tags: python

I have data of this form

```
34950388,"Bodycology Scarlet Kiss Fragrance Mist, 8 fl oz","<p>Turn heads    
with our intoxicating fragrance made with rich pomegranate, luscious peach   
and warm vanilla. Be confident, and you're sure to be a showstopper!
</p>","<B>Bodycology Scarlet Kiss Fragrance Mist, 8 fl oz:</b><ul><li>For 
a splash of fragrance and energy, spritz lightly on wrists, neck and 
shoulders.<li>Top Notes: Juicy Pomegranate, Peach Skin, Macintosh 
Apple<li>Middle Notes: Red Peony, Osmanthus, Marshmallow Creme<li>Dry 
Notes: Rich, Vanilla Rum, Oakwood, Scarlet Musk</ul>",None,,
```

I want to read this data and split it based on the commas in text such that my output after splitting will be:

```
34950388

"Bodycology Scarlet Kiss Fragrance Mist, 8 fl oz"

 "<p>Turn heads with our intoxicating fragrance made with rich     
 pomegranate, luscious peach and warm vanilla. Be confident, and you're  
sure to be a showstopper!</p>"

"<B>Bodycology Scarlet Kiss Fragrance Mist, 8 fl oz:</b><ul><li>For 
a splash of fragrance and energy, spritz lightly on wrists, neck and 
shoulders.<li>Top Notes: Juicy Pomegranate, Peach Skin, Macintosh 
Apple<li>Middle Notes: Red Peony, Osmanthus, Marshmallow Creme<li>Dry 
Notes: Rich, Vanilla Rum, Oakwood, Scarlet Musk</ul>"

None
```

How I can do this without using any library(Numpy, Pandas) from Python?

Comment: What did you try and what doesn't work?

Comment: where come from your data ? what did you try ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can split by commas not enclosed by quotes using regex:

```
,(?=(?:[^"]*"[^"]*")*[^"]*$)
```

Assuming your data is `text`, then using the `re` module and `re.split`:

```
import re
for line in re.split(',(?=(?:[^"]*"[^"]*")*[^"]*$)', text):
    print(line)
    print()
```

Which outputs:

```
34950388

"Bodycology Scarlet Kiss Fragrance Mist, 8 fl oz"

"<p>Turn headswith our intoxicating fragrance made with rich pomegranate, luscious peach and warm vanilla. Be confident, and you're sure to be a showstopper! </p>"

"<B>Bodycology Scarlet Kiss Fragrance Mist, 8 fl oz:</b><ul><li>For a splash of fragrance and energy, spritz lightly on wrists, neck and shoulders.<li>Top Notes: Juicy Pomegranate, Peach Skin, Macintosh Apple<li>Middle Notes: Red Peony, Osmanthus, Marshmallow Creme<li>Dry Notes: Rich, Vanilla Rum, Oakwood, Scarlet Musk</ul>"

None
```